# Compare 2 columns in different tables mysql

Tags: mysql, compare

I have two tables that contain business info the first one lets call it A has (id,info,category) the second one lets call it B has (id,phone,category).

The A.info contains address, phone and other info.
The B.phone contains just a phone number.

I would like to set the B.category as the A.category where the B.phone exists in A.info.

I was thinking something like that:

```
update A
inner B
set B.category = A.category
where B.phone like %A.phone%
```

With no luck offcourse

Comment: 1) Do both ids match? 2) In case they don't, what happens if more than one record from A have the same phone number and different categories?

Comment: ids do not match there is a section column in both tables too. So the duplicates wont be an issue. Actually I was looking in to how use wildcards with a column (something like %column%), but I found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, give this query a try:

```
update b, a
set b.category = a.category
where a.info like concat('%', b.phone, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are providing the the literal A.Phone value instead of the actual column value.

You mentioned using wildcards as well in one of your comments. You could use REGEXP if you need more granular control as well.

I am not sure what your column data types are but here is an example to match the records 
where a.info REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]', b.phone, '[[:>:]]')